How to run python code "directly" via IDE as well as using python -m projectname from terminal? (terminal only works now)
I've set up a python project using this guid: https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6
I can execute my code using python -m myprojectname from terminal
However When I open Spyder (my current IDE) and go to __main__.py or mainapp.py I get an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named myprojectname
Im vaguely aware that when importing within your own project if __name__=='__main__' the import fails but when executing with python -m ... then the import is successful. As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11537218/23994290
Is it possible to have an ability with out too much added complexity to run the code via IDE and via the terminal?
Alternatively I can experimental install my package pip3 install -e myprojectname
However when trying this method I can't seam to import the package, I get module not found even though I can see it listed in pip and pip says it installed successfully
The reason I would like to run form IDE is to use spiders debug features or really any of the IDE features.  If you can hep me understand how to set up my code to run both via IDE and from terminal that would be helpful.  Im realizing as I type this that the team using this might be installing via pip or via conda.  This is my first attempt to create a "real" python package for others to use.  Thanks for any help.

my file structure:
myprojectname-git/
├─ myprojectanem/
│  ├─ extract/
│  │  ├─ dfhelper.py
│  │  ├─ extract.py
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ plot/
│  │  ├─ heatmaps.py
│  │  ├─ scorecard.py
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ mainapp.py
│  ├─ settings.yaml
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ __main__.py
├─ setup.py



setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="myprojectname",
    version="0.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["myprojectname = myprojectname.__main__:main"]
    }
)




I tried to install my own package via pip install -e myprojectname
I tried to directly run __main__.py as well as mainapp.py
I tried to use relative imports in my project
I tried to use absolute imports in my project
I was expecting to be able to run my code both via terminal python -m myprojectname' and via and IDE such as spyder.  However only the terminal executes.   spyder gives me the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named myprojectname`
